# Writing an Inner Product Space as a Direct Sum

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, orthogonality

Suppose that $V$ is an inner product space and $W$ is a closed linear subspace of $V$ (closed in the metric topology on $V$, where the metric topology is induced by the inner product). Is it true that $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$?

Comment: I think you need to work in a Hilbert space for this to hold.

Comment: @egreg Shoot! I was hoping that I didn't have to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in a Hilbert space, no in general.

Let $V$ be the space of all polynomials, with the inner product
$$\langle p, q\rangle=\int_0^1pq$$(or $\int_0^1p\overline q$ if you want a complex inner product space). Let $W$ be the subspace consisting of all $p$ such that $$\int_0^1p(t)e^t\,dt=0.$$Then $W\ne V$, but the orthogonal complement of $W$ *in $V$* is $\{0\}$.

Proof: Let $\overline W$ be the closure of $W$ in $L^2([0,1])$. Then $\overline W$ is the space of all $f\in L^2$ with $\int_0^1f(t)e^t\,dt=0$. So the orthogonal complement of $\overline W$ in $L^2$ is spanned by $e^t$; hence it contains no non-zero polynomial.

Comment: So, no in general...Are there further constraints we can place on $W$ that will guarantee such a conclusion holds? Specifically I am working with $W = \ker \phi$, where $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $V$ (in fact, the metric topology on $V$ is such that all linear functionals are continuous). But $\ker \phi$ may have more properties I am unaware of.

Comment: Well, if you look at that example you see that $W=\ker\phi$...

Comment: @user193319 All linear functionals are continuous? Then $V$ is finite-dimensional, hence complete.

Answer (score 2):

No.  For instance, let $W$ be the subspace of $\ell^2$ which is the span (not the closed span!) of the standard basis vectors $e_{2n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $V$ be the span of $W$ and the sequence $v=(1/n)$.  Then $W$ is a closed proper subspace of $V$, but $W^\perp=0$.

More generally, if you take an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$, a non-closed subspace $W\subset H$, and a vector $v\in H$ which is not in $\overline{W}$ and whose projection onto $\overline{W}$ is not in $W$, then $V=W+\mathbb{C}v$ will similarly give a counterexample.